# Android Room Database. How to add my Model class into Room database

Tags: android, database, orm, android-architecture-components

I ran into the problem of adding my model class to the Room database. I've read about @Relation, @Embedded, but I can not figure out what to do with my model class.

Here my model class which comes from the server. I need to store this data

```
public class ResultsItem {

private String model;
private int id;
private int distanceLon;
private String brand;

//*PROMBLEM HERE*
private List<BidsItem> bids;

//*PROMBLEM HERE*
private User user;

//*PROMBLEM HERE*
private List<FotosItem> fotos;


// getters/setters...

}
```

FotosItem class

```
public class FotosItem {
private String imageUrl;
private int resultItemId;
private int id;

//getters/setters

}
```

BidsItem class

```
public class BidsItem {
private double distanceToAuto;
private boolean isWin;
private int sum;
private String currency;
private int id;

//getters/setters

}
```

I will be very grateful if someone tells me what I need to do, or at least in what direction to move

Comment: If you want to save a class in a databsae, you have to convert it into a byte array (apache commons lang has a tool for this, but you can create it on your own if you feel like it) and then you put that into the database using a blob field. Load it using getBlob and use apache lang to convert the byte stream back into the class

Comment: @LunarWatcher thx for quick comment, but i also need use `LiveData<>` for getting new data which was added to Room database. This data comes from server when paginate next portion of data

Comment: Um, well, we cannot really help you much, as we have no idea what `BidsItem`, `User`, or `FotosItem` are. We do not know the nature of the relationship between `ResultsItem` and these other things (e.g., does a `User` have one `ResultsItem` or N possible `ResultItem` instances)? Most likely, all of these are entities, and you need to determine where the foreign keys go, based on the type of relationship you have. Ignore `@Relation`. At most, `User` might be `@Embedded`, if there is a pure 1:1 relationship between `ResultsItem` and `User`.

Comment: I am added `BidsItem` and `FotosItem` code above

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by doing some tweek in DAO class. Use Ignore Annotation for List.

```
public class ResultsItem {

private String model;
private int id;
private int distanceLon;
private String brand;

@Ignore
private List<BidsItem> bids;

private User user;

@Ignore
private List<FotosItem> fotos;


// getters/setters...

}
```

FotosItem class

```
public class FotosItem {
private String imageUrl;
private int resultItemId;
private int id;

//getters/setters

}
```

BidsItem class

```
public class BidsItem {
private double distanceToAuto;
private boolean isWin;
private int sum;
private String currency;
private int id;

//getters/setters

}
```

Now DAO Class

```
@Dao
public abstract class DBAccess {

@Insert
public abstract void insertBids(List<BidsItem> pets);

@Insert
public abstract void insertFotos(List<FotosItem> pets);

@Insert
public abstract void insertResultItem(ResultsItem resultItem);

public void insertResultWithBidsFotos(ResultsItem resultItem) {
        insertBids(resultItem.getBids());
        insertFotos(resultItem.getFotos());
        insertResultItem(resultItem);
    }

}
```

Same you can Implement for retrieve.